# Powershell - Incorrect Array Count when piping ForEach-Object

Tags: powershell

I don't understand why I get the correct count of my array when using ForEach, but not when I pipe to ForEach-Object. The piped count is always 0.

Correct Count:

```
$hash = @(Get-ChildItem C:\Dir -Recurse -Include *.txt | Where {$_.length -gt 0})
ForEach ($i in @hash) {
     Write-Host = $i.BaseName
}
"Array Count = $($hash.Count)"
```

Output:

```
File1.txt
File2.txt
Array Count = 2
```

Incorrect Count:

```
$hash = @(Get-ChildItem C:\Dir -Recurse -Include *.txt | Where {$_.length -gt 0}) | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host $_.BaseName
}
"Array Count = $($hash.Count)"
```

Output:

```
File1.txt
File2.txt
Array Count = 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your second formulation the `ForEach-Object` is eating up the values found by
`Get-ChildItem` and returning nothing useful to `$hash`.

You should enclose the entire assignment to `$hash` in the parenthesis to have it
evaluated before it is grabbed by `ForEach-Object`.

This is the formulation that worked for me in my test:

```
($hash=@(Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Temp\*" -Include "*.jpg") | Where {$_.length -gt 0}) | ForEach-Object { Write-Host $_.BaseName }
```

Comment: that works great. Thanks for the great explanation.

Comment: My next questions is how to display the current index being processed. I'm wanting to write to a log something like 1 of 4, 2 of 4, etc

Comment: That would need to be asked in another post.

Answer (score 0):

$hash is null in the second example (type `$hash -eq $null` to verify). The output of the pipeline is "consumed" by the Write-host in your loop --- there's nothing left to assign to $hash. If you want the names assigned to $hasn and displayed on the console, something like this would work:

```
$hash = @(Get-ChildItem c:\dir -Recurse -Include *.txt | Where {$_.length -gt 0}) | ForEach-Object {
    $_.BaseName # continues through pipeline to populate $hash
    write-host $_.basename
} 
"Array Count = $($hash.Count)"
```